# Raising 403 forbidden in django-rest-framework doesn't work

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST framework to make user submit their works. I am restricting the user submissions according to their subscribed plan. I am doing that by raising 403 forbidden with a message whenever user tries to add more than his quota.

This is what I wanted and it works perfectly in my local machine, but it shows a weird "OOPs something went wrong" message on my staging. In preview it shows "Failed to load response Data". I don't know why. I used the same staging database on local machine. Even then, it worked.

The code I used for the both places are same.

Comment: What does your apache / nginx / whatever you're using webserver logs say about it ?

Comment: I was checking on chrome. In request headers it says "Provisional headers are shown". In logs it says " 172.31.7.235 - - [19/Mar/2018:07:05:50 +0000] "POST /api/companies/offices/XXXX/submission/? HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "https://XXXX.com/my/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "

Comment: I got 403 here.But the cleint cannot recieve that.

Comment: you should see if posting to a regular Django page works, might be an issue with ALLOWS_HOSTS.

Comment: Thanks But,I used javascript way of handling it before it reach the server.May not be reliable,but works for now.